# Improve Log Exceptions

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, hash

I am planning to use `log4net` in a new web project. In my experience, I see how big the log table can get, also I notice that errors or exceptions are repeated. For instance, I just query a log table that have more than 132.000 records, and I using distinct and found that only 2.500 records are unique (~2%), the others (~98%) are just duplicates. so, I came up with this idea to improve logging.

Having a couple of new columns: `counter` and `updated_dt`, that are updated every time try to insert same record.

If want to track the user that cause the exception, need to create a `user_log` or log_user table, to map N-N relationship.

Create this model may made the system slow and inefficient trying to compare all these long text... Here the trick, we should also has a `hash column` of binary of 16 or 32, that hash the message and the exception, and configure an index on it. We can use [`HASHBYTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) to help us.
I am not an expert in DB, but I think that will made the faster way to locate a similar record. And because hashing doesn't guarantee uniqueness, will help to locale those similar record much faster and later compare by message or exception directly to make sure that are unique.

This is a theoretical/practical solution, but will it work or bring more complexity? what aspects I am leaving out or what other considerations need to have? the trigger will do the job of insert or update, but is the trigger the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be too concerned with a log table of 132,000 records to be honest, I have seen millions, if not billions of records in a log table. If you are logging out 132,000 records every **few minutes** then you might want to tone it down a bit.

I think the idea is interesting but here is my major concerns:

- **You could actually hurt the performance of your application by doing this.** The Log4Net ADO.NET appender is synchronous. This means if you make your INSERT anymore complicated than it needs to be (aka looking up if the data already exists, calculating hash codes etc.) you will block the thread calling logging. That's not good! You could fix this writing to some sort of a staging table and doing it out of band with a job or something but now you've created a bunch of moving parts for something that could be much simpler.
- Time could probably be better spent doing other things. Storage is cheap, developer hours aren't and logs don't need to be extremely fast to access so a denormalized model should be fine.

Thoughts?

Comment: that 132,000 records was from a log table of that contains records within last 15 days... so over a year will easily get the million records.
But maybe your right, and I don't need to worry about it in my small (scalable) app.
I was more concern about the analysis and auditing about it... but as you mentioned, that shouldn't be that often.

Comment: You also give me an idea, of having the two system instead... (1) log everything, and in the other side, (2) create a log_summary table within a stored procedure.

Comment: You could do something like that in a SQL Job, log to the 'fast' (doesn't hash) table and then parse later and delete from the 'fast' table at that time. This would cause it to be async from the logging process which is ideal. In that same job it might not be a bad plan to include deleting log entries older than a couple months as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. It is a good idea and it will work. Watch out for concurrency issues when inserting from multiple threads or processes. You probably need to investigate locking in detail. You should look into locking hints (in your case `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK`) and the `MERGE` statement. They can be used to maintain the dimension table.

As an alternative you could log to a file and compress it. Typical compression algorithms are very good at eliminating this type of exact redundancy.